# Issue with aliases in Terminal shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, alias

I'm set **/bin/bash** as my default shell in Terminal (macos) and my aliases, written in **'~/.bashrc'** don't work (command not found).

But if I write in Terminal `/bin/bash` command, I'll switch to new bash3.2 shell, and then I can use it.

Is there some another **'.bashrc'** where I should write down my aliases?

P.S. I used Terminal preferences to made **/bin/bash** default 
and `chsh -s /bin/bash/` command too.

Comment: From the bash man page: `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.` . Use functions instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : If .bashrc is not sourced at all, as it seems to be the case, it would not read the functions either.

Comment: @eduard: First verify whether or not .bashrc is sourced by your Terminal; right now, it seems that this is not the case. Put a `set -x` on top of your .bashrc, then open a new Terminal session.

Comment: Also, in your bash shell, what does `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `echo $-` say?

Comment: @eduard : My mistake - I just found one sentence in the _bash man page_, which says, that even in _interactive_ login shells, .bashrc is not sourced. Hence, the solution given by chepner is correct.

Comment: @user1934428 That is correct.  My comment is not intended to answer the question (if it were, it would be an answer!)  I am merely commenting on the fact that aliases should not be used anymore.  They've been effectively deprecated for decades.

Answer (score 5):

`Terminal` starts a login shell rather than an "ordinary" interactive shell, because Terminal itself is not run from a shell that inherited an environment from a login shell.

Ordinary interactive shells source `.bashrc`; login shells source the first of `.profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.bash_profile` it finds. I recommend sourcing `.bashrc` directly from `.bash_profile`.

Your aliases work when you run `/bin/bash` directly because that does *not* start another login shell, and so `.bashrc` is sourced as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As above, if you add the following line to `.profile` in your home directory:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Once you save it and create a new Terminal session, it will automatically source your `.bashrc` with your alias settings.

Answer (score 0):

You want `/bin/bash -l` to run as if you used a login shell. See the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash` for more information.

Comment: This would not run .bashrc. From the bash man page: _When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as  a  non-interactive  shell  with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it  looks  for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order_